# Ajax image load after dropzone success event

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5.1

So I am using dropzone.js and I want to reload a particular image after the success event of dropzone.

my controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $offer = Offer::find($id);

    if(!is_object($offer->getMedia('featimgs')->first())){
        $offerfeatimg = '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg';
    } else {
        $offerfeatimg = $offer->getMedia('featimgs')->first()->getUrl('medium');
    }

    return view('admin.offers.edit')->with(compact('offer', 'offerfeatimg'));
}
```

so this is where I pass the image to the view:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <img src="{{ $offerfeatimg }}" class="img-responsive">
            @if($offerfeatimg != '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg')
            <div class="removebutton">
                <a href="/admin/offer/featimg/delete/{{ $offer->id }}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Izbrisi sliku</a>
            </div>
            @endif
            <form action="/admin/offer/featimg/{{ $offer->id }}" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="dz-message">Prebacite glavnu sliku za ovu ponudu</div>
            </form>

        </div>
```

the view:

so I would want to reload this part via ajax after success dropzone event:

```
<img src="{{ $offerfeatimg }}" class="img-responsive">
            @if($offerfeatimg != '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg')
            <div class="removebutton">
                <a href="/admin/offer/featimg/delete/{{ $offer->id }}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Izbrisi sliku</a>
            </div>
            @endif
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            parallelUploads: 1,
            success: function (file, response) {
                var imageSrc = response;
                $(".img-responsive").attr('src', imageSrc);
                if(imageSrc == '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg') {
                    $(".removebutton").hide();
                } else {
                    $(".removebutton").show();
                }

                this.removeAllFiles();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming a bit about your javascript setup, including jquery. If the dropzone object is available on the form node, you should be able to do something like this in javascript:

```
var dz = $('form.dropzone').get(0).dropzone;

dz.on("success", function (file, response) {
  var imageSrc = ... // add logic here to determine src from server response
  $(".img-responsive").attr('src', imageSrc);
  if(imageSrc != '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg') {
    $(".removebutton").hide();
  }
  else {
    // you may need to edit your html so that this button exists in order to show it
    $(".removebutton").show();
  }
});
```

Or you can set up event handlers like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  ... other options ...,
  success: function () {
    ...
  }
};
```

Take a look at handling dropzone events: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Comment: my response when i sent the image via dropzone is the actually image path.

but how do I use that response at var imageSrc = response ?

Comment: Ok great, i got it working. Now I actually need to add the remove button if
if(imageSrc != '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg')

Comment: maybe you want to use `$(".removebutton").hide()` and `$(".removebutton").show()` based on the value of `imageSrc`? I'll edit my answer in case that's what you need.

Comment: success: function (file, response) {
                    var imageSrc = response;
                    $(".img-responsive").attr('src', imageSrc);
                    if(imageSrc == '/assets/images/offerfeatimg.jpg') {
                        $(".removebutton").hide();
                    } else {
                        $(".removebutton").show();
                    }
                }

not working

Comment: @AdnanMujkanovic Not working how? What is happening exactly? Hopefully you're putting some `console.log` or `alert` calls in there to help yourself do some debugging.